# How to submit CActiveForm files by using ajax

Tags: jquery, yii, ajaxform

I have an *[CActiveForm](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm)* with the *[CMultiFileUpload](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CMultiFileUpload)* widget. 
The user can upload files this way.

When the form is submit. The appropriate action is executed, 
the files are being uploaded and then redirects back to the page.
Thus showing the newly uploaded images.

But how can I submit the form in an ajax way?

I tried using jQuery Ajax but the **$_FILES** array is empty.

I want to upload the images by ajax one by one. The server then uploads them
and returns them with JSON encoding. Which then the javascript 
will receive and place in the HTML DOM.

Comment: You can use base64 encode.

Answer (score 0):

Files field can't be upload by Ajax. Instead you may use http://www.plupload.com/example_queuewidget.php